# Branching rule for $S_n$ proof by James

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux, branching-rules

Apologies for my English in advanced..

The following is a part from James' proof for the branching rule on the symmetric group:
[image]

It can be found in "The Representation Theory of the Symmetric Groups" by James in page 34.
Another proof, based on the above, can be found here: https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2011/01/28/the-branching-rule-part-2/

I can't seem to understand the definition for $\theta_i$ on a polytabloid $e_t$.

> What if $n$ shows up in row $r_{i+1}$?

e.g. if we take $e_t$ to be the polytabloid generated by the standard tabloid $1 2 3//4$.
we get $e_t = 1 2 3//4 - 4 2 3//1$.

Acting on $e_t$ with $\theta_1$ force us to remove $4$ from the first row, leaving us with a structure that is not a Young tableau.

So I tried writing $2 3 4//1$ (the representative of row class in which $4 2 3//1$ is) instead.
We get $\theta_1(e_t) = \theta_1(1 2 3//4 - 2 3 4//1) = 0 - 2 3//1$ which is not equal to $e_{t^1}$ or $0$..

Can you please help me make the definition of $\theta_i$ on $\{t\}$ coincide
with its definition on $e_t$?

Comment: 9.4 does not mention the effect of $\theta_i$ on $e_t$ when $n$ belongs to the $r_{i+1}$th rot of $t$. So what is the issue?

Comment: I gave an example of a valid situation like that, for which it is not clear to me how $\theta_i$ acts. If it is clear to you, it would be helpful if you could clarify the solution for this specific example. Of course, if you have a more general solution, it would also be appreciated.

Comment: I'm saying, what is wrong with $\theta_1(e_t)=-23//1$? $4$ lies in row 2. You are acting with $\theta_1$. 9.4 does not make any statement about this situation.

Comment: That's a surprisingly good point. Later in the proof he really doesn't use this fact. So in order for the definition to be valid, you're implying I should take the representative 234//1 as I did in the latter part, instead of 423//1, which I took in the first part?

Comment: You shouldn't be taking any representative. Removing 4 from the tabloid 432//1 yields the tabloid 23//1, or 32//1, they are the same thing. As tabloids don't care about the order of the elements in the list, of course you may remove 4 from 432 to end up with 32, not _32.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that.. It's just that in the second row of the proof, James specifically states that $r_1,...,r_k$ refer only to row that removing a node from leaves a valid diagram.

Comment: And of course, thanks for the replies!

Comment: He says removing a node from $[\mu]$, a Young diagram, not $\{t\}$, a tabloid.